# Is it possible to set two background images with different positioning in css

Tags: html, css, background, alignment

I have div that has two styles, Aligned left and aligned right. The BG on the left is aligned into position. I understand that to set multiple backgrounds I would use this.

```
background: url(../assests/icons/dialog_left_point.png) left top no-repeat,
```

url(../assests/icons/dialog_left_bg.png) 15px top repeat-y;

CSS aligns the image X pixels from the left and then X pixels from the top, which works fine for aligning the background image from the left. As you can see in the example.

[image: left align working]

This is the CSS for that to align the image form the right to duplicate the effect for the right hand side.

```
.default .msg_text_right{
    background:url(../assests/icons/dialog_right_point.png) right top no-repeat;
}
```

As you can see the image of the arrow shows up but nothing else. I tried adding this:

```
.default .msg_text_right::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
    background:url(../assests/icons/dialog_right_bg.png) right top repeat-y;
}
```

Which results in only the arrow showing up. I happen to think I'm pretty close but I can't figure out why nothing is loaded in for the ::after tag.

Here is my full code in-case it helps this shows the CSS for the size of the containers and the style of the containers:

```
.default .msg_text{
    background: url(../assests/icons/dialog_left_point.png) left top no-repeat, url(../assests/icons/dialog_left_bg.png) 15px top repeat-y;
}
.default .msg_text_right{
    background:url(../assests/icons/dialog_right_point.png) right top no-repeat;
}
.default .msg_text_right::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
    background:url(../assests/icons/dialog_right_bg.png) right top repeat-y;
}
.msg_data li .msg_text, .msg_data li .msg_text_right{
    width:auto;
    max-width:55%;
    min-height:18px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:16px;
    color:#000;
    padding-top:11px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    font-family:'coertschrift_dikregular';
}
.msg_data li .msg_text{
    float:left;
    left:40px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:25px;
}
.msg_data li .msg_text_right{
    float:right;
    right:40px;
    padding-right:25px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

HTML/PHP

```
$d = '';
    $data = '<div id="inner_content">
    <ul class="msg_data default">';
```

> <---- The div has two css styles one for the shape and one for the
>   style

```
    for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++){
        $data .= '
        <li>
            <div class="pp'.$d.'"><img src="assests/profile.png" /></div>
            <div class="msg_text'.$d.'">Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user Messge text from user </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </li>
       ';
       if($d == '_right'){
           $d = '';
       }else{
           $d = '_right';
       }
    }
    $data .= '</ul></div>';
    die(json_encode(array('err' => 0, 'err_msg' => 'Some error message', 'msg' => $data)));
```

Comment: Please refine the scentences between your code blocks (at least I did not understand what you're after). Please tell us the dimensions and the transparency of your images too (this could matter).

Comment: It seems you can't use `px` positioning together with background repeat. Firefox 27 warns about malformed CSS when I change a value to `NNpx` (http://jsfiddle.net/pzqJ2/1/). Further the images are stacked in the order with most **top image** on the **left hand side**.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

Well, the website says you can use:

```
background-position:left top, 95% top
```

You can tweak with the percentage to get the desired effect? I'm not familiar with other ways to do it..

However, you can do it programmatically: http://jsfiddle.net/fW9ZA/

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var width = test.offsetWidth - 215;

test.setAttribute('style', 'background-position:left top, ' + width + 'px top ');
```

---

It's possible with css3:

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

You should check google first before you post a question on stackoverflow.

Good luck!

Comment: doesn't answer the question how to set the second image x amount of pixels form the right. The problem isn't with applying multiple backgrounds